# Converting decimal number to binary in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that converts a decimal number into a binary. I made it that far and I stuck with a problem. In the code with `print(aa)`.

I tried to get a binary form of given number but it prints 1. I think I have "return" function problem here how can I solve it. Also, when I print `binaryform` it prints like the way below. Shouldn't it print reversely I mean first 1 and then 11 and then 111 .......10111.

```
# Python program to convert decimal number into binary number using recursive function
def binary(n, binaryform,i):
   if n >= 1:
       digit= n % 2
       binaryform += digit*i
       #print(binaryform)
       i*=10
       binary(n/2, binaryform, i)
       print("xxx", binaryform)
       return binaryform
dec = int(input("Enter an integer: "))# Take decimal number from user
aa = binary(dec, 0, 1)
print(aa)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter an integer: 23    
('xxx', 10111)    
('xxx', 111)    
('xxx', 111)    
('xxx', 11)       
('xxx', 1)    
1
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin

Answer (score 0):

> Convert an integer number to a binary string. The result is a valid Python expression. If x is not a Python int object, it has to define an **index**() method that returns an integer. [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a recursive function - that's fun and good.

Now consider what you do: you check the LOW part of the number. If the LOW part of the number is 1 or 0 you do something, but then you shrink the number and recurse, checking a new LOW part, but the new low part came from a HIGHER part originally.

So whatever you determine should actually be at the end of the string, not the beginning, when you come back from recursion.

That's your question about printing reversely, I think. And yes, except you should just assemble it reversely, and then print it normally.

Also, you're actually trying to construct a decimal integer that will print out as if it were a binary number. It would be a lot simpler if you just constructed a string: "10101".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert integer to binary, try this code [here](http://movingtofreedom.org/2010/10/28/easy-binary-decimal-denary-conversions-in-python-2-6/) . It looks like this :

```
def binary(n):
    b = ''
    while n > 0:
        b = str(n % 2) + b
        n >>= 1
    print(b)

binary(10)
```